# Create output Xml file from XML and XSD using DataSet

Tags: xamarin.android, dataset

I've got two example files: note.xml and note.xsd. I would like to combine this two files using DataSet and create output XML file, based on this operation. How can i do it?

**note.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

**note.xsd**

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="note">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

**UPDATE**

Basically, i would like to combine XSD and XML and create output XML file. I want to use something like data table relations(DataSet)
Then after combine, we can decide based on data type(string, int..), which for example: dataform can store this.

Comment: Based on my research, you should read .xml and .xsd file separately, then will get two datasets, get the data from the dataTable in dataset. Merge these data by key-value format.

Comment: Could you give me some example code?

Comment: Did you use `DataSet.Merge` method like this thread? please set the demo code(use insert.update the table) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.merge?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Basically, i would like to combine XSD and XML and create output XML file. I want to use something like data table relations(DataSet) Then after combine, we can decide based on data type(string, int..), which for example: dataform can store this.